# MS Project - Task constraints based on dates of other tasks

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

I would like to be able to set task constraints based on dates relative to other tasks, for instance:
*"taskA to start no earlier than taskB end date + 20 days"*
is there a way to do it? In MS Project I only shows absolute dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Project - how to calculate start dates based on a set time from the finish date?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/26475/microsoft-project-how-to-calculate-start-dates-based-on-a-set-time-from-the-fi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by linking tasks and creating dependencies between them.

From memory, while on the Gantt screen, ensure that the Predecessor column is shown. In the example you give, let's assume TaskB is in row 24 and TaskA is in row 25 of the page. In the "Predecessor" column of row 25, enter 24FS+20d.

There is an explanation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/project-management-goal-create-a-new-project-schedule-in-project-desktop-91e314ed-af31-4043-be6f-61a7ea0d89ba) which gives you the basics of using MS Project (you will have to navigate through a couple of pages) although it may be slightly different for different versions of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but to me it seems relative to something simpler than my question, it seems to be missing the "no earlier than". BTW I wonder whether a simple dependency as you suggest would have the same effect, at firtst sight it might seem so but I would need to be 100% sure before going for it, currently do notr feel 100% sure

Comment: The way you asked your question, @Iain9688's answer is 100% correct.  FS+20 is the logic you would load in the predecessor field (adding the task row, of course).  If there is another problem you're trying to solve, update your question.

Comment: If there are other dependencies on other tasks, MS Project will honour all of the dependency constraints. This will apply a "no earlier than" date to all of the individual dependencies.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic my question was about task constraints, that in MS project are not the same thing as task dependencies. As pedantry is not a good thing I will accept the answer and go for an FS even though there isn't any of the usual dependencies and a constraint seemed conceptually more appropriate.

Comment: You can set constraints on tasks in MS project at a task level, such that you can say "Start no earlier than {date}", but as I no longer have access to a copy of MS Project (having retired from work!) I can't recall exactly how to do that. This should, I believe, work in conjunction with dependencies so the dependency and the constraint will work together to give you the "Don't start until at least {date} AND Only start at least 20 days after the predecessor task" that I think may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @user778806 Yes, constraints and dependencies are two different things. As Iaia9688 pointed out, constraints are defined by a date and a type and have nothing to do with other tasks. A task's start date can be driven by a constraint, dependencies to other tasks, and/or calendars (task and/or resource). There is no such thing as "constraints based on...other tasks", that would be a dependency. [How Project schedules tasks: Behind the scenes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-project-schedules-tasks-behind-the-scenes-df3431ab-8d8a-4047-afc6-a87b547dbac0) might be useful.

Comment: @RachelHettinger The difference between constraints and dependencies is clear to me, the content of the post you quoted is known to me, it is unrelated to my question.
The question was "In MS Prj  would like to be able to set task constraints based on dates relative to other tasks ... is there a way to do it?". 
The question was not "I wonder what a constraint is, I wonder what a dependency is Etc."
The answer seems to be "no" as no way was suggested.